# Does ozone have polar bonds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, polarity, ozone

Does $\ce{O3}$ have polar or non-polar bonds? My teacher says that $\ce{O3}$ has non-polar bonds.
But chem-libre texts and many other sources state that a non-polar bond has equal distribution of electrons, which doesn't seem to be the case in $\ce{O3}$.
(Not asking whether the molecule $\ce{O3}$ is polar but rather if the bonds in $\ce{O3}$ are polar.)

Comment: Nonpolar bonds have insignificant partial charge on respective atoms. Ask yourself if it is the case of [ozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone)

Comment: @poutnik yes it does have the partial charge. Is the bond non polar?  A bond is said to be polar when there is even distribution of electrons between atoms. But the distribution (from what I have seen in the electron density graphs that isn't the case.)

Comment: A bond is said to be **non polar** when there is (about) even distribution of (bond) electrons between atoms. When this distribution is shifted toward one of atoms, forming partial atom charges, such a bond is polar.

Comment: To complement my old comment, electronegativity-wise non-polar bond can be polarized by already existing opposite charges on the bound atoms, as is in the ozone case.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the bonds are non-polar and the partial charge is due to the imbalance in non-bonding electrons. However, once there is a dipole due to those, you would induce a shift in the bonding electrons as well.

This view is mostly an artifact of a single electron wave function view.  The reality is a bit more holistic with a wave function that describes multiple indistinguishable electrons, so the important thing is the actual dipole moment, not assigning “blame” for it.

Answer (score 0):

As we know resonance operates in Ozone molecule, so bond order between O-O bind is 1.5
As in the resonance hybrid, there is evrn distribution of electrons between O-O bonds, I think so that it is non-polar [image: Resonance in ozone and formation of Resonance hybrid]